# problem with rails - "Could not find gem 'pg"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

bonjour dudes.
i have a small problem with rails.
today i install rails 3 and decided create a new project.

```
rails new blablabla --database=postgresql
```

i edited database.yml and paste to it my databases, logins and passwords of postgres.
my postgresql works on port 5433 (instead of 5432)
database.yml example:

```
development:
adapter: postgresql
database: devdb
encoding: utf8
username: postgres
password: mypassword
host: localhost
port: 5433
```

i just want to start server, or add controller, but rails says:

```
Could not find gem 'pg (>= 0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile
```

but i have 'pg'. i think problem with port, but i dont know how fix problem.

sorry for bad english, and thanks for answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would appear from the error message that you are using Bundler to manage your gems for the project.  Have you tried running `bundle install` to bring all of your sources in the Gemfile up to date?  Here is an example:

```
> bundle install
Using rake (0.8.7) 
Using abstract (1.0.0) 
Using activesupport (3.0.3) 
[...]
Using zendesk_remote_auth (0.9.0) 
Your bundle is complete! Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

Comment: Installing pg (0.10.1) with native extensions /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/installer.rb:533:in `build_extensions': ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

Comment: Sounds like progress.  What does the rest of the error message and stack trace say?  I am guessing your system library is missing something not allowing the extension to compile.